# Are the features of Word2Vec independent each other?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, text-classification, word-embedding

I am new to NLP and studying Word2Vec. So I am not fully understanding the concept of Word2Vec.

Are the features of Word2Vec independent each other?

For example, suppose there is a 100-dimensional word2vec. Then the 100 features are independent each other? In other words, if the "sequence" of the features are shuffled, then the meaning of word2vec is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word2vec is a 'dense' embedding: the individual dimensions generally aren't independently interpretable. It's just the 'neighborhoods' and 'directions' (not limited to the 100 orthogonal axis dimensions) that have useful meanings.

So, they're not 'independent' of each other in a statistical sense. But, you can discard any of the dimensions – for example, the last 50 dimensions of all your 100-dimensional vectors – and you still have usable word-vectors. So in that sense they're still independently useful.

If you shuffled the order-of-dimensions, the same way for every vector in your set, you've then essentially just rotated/reflected all the vectors similarly. They'll all have different coordinates, *but* their relative distances will be the same, and if "going toward word B from word A" used to vaguely indicate some human-understandable aspect like "largeness", then even after performing your order-of-dimensions shuffle, "going towards word B from word A" will mean the same thing, because the vectors "thataway" (in the transformed coordinates) will be the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand here is that how word2Vec is formalized. Shifting away from traditional representations of words, the word2vec model tries to encode the meaning of the world into different features. For eg lets say every word in the english dictionary can be manifested in a set of say '4' features. The features could be , lets say "f1":"gender", "f2":"color","f3":"smell","f4":"economy".

So now when a word2vec vector is written , what it signifies is how much manifestation of a particular feature it has. Lets take an example to understand this. Consider a Man(V1) who is dark,not so smelly and is not very rich and is neither poor. Then the first feature ie gender is represented as 1 (since we are taking 1 as male and -1 as female). The second feature color is -1 here as it is exactly opposite to white (which we are taking as 1). Smell and economy are similary given 0.3 and 0.4 values.
Now consider another man(V2) who also has the same anatomy and social status like the first man. Then his word2vec vector would also be similar.

V1=>[1,-1,0.3,0.4]

V2=>[1,-1,0.4,0.3]

This kind of representation helps us represent words into features that are independent or orthogonal to each other.The orthogonality helps in finding similarity or dissimilarity based on some mathematical operation lets say cosine dot product.
The sequence of the number in a word2vec is important since every number represents the weight of a particular feature: gender, color,smell,economy. So shuffling the positions would result in a completely different vector